# elements are not replaced with lreplace command

Tags: function, tcl

I found an exercise of Tcl language :

**Write a procedure that returns all commands that are visible to the caller that are not procedures.**

So after several attemps I ended with this code:

```
proc aaaaaaaaaa {} { set var 1} ; # name is not important

proc only_commands {} {
set rawList [info commands]
set procList [info proc]

foreach a $procList {
    set pos [lsearch $rawList $a]
    lreplace $rawList $pos $pos
}
return $rawList
}

puts [ only_commands ]
```

In this code I got two lists: one of command (including procedures) and one of only procedures.
Now I used a foreach loop for get the position of element in the 
command's list and replace it with nothing. At the end I returned the list.

But, when I print the list, I see also the procedure "aaaaaaaaaa".

```
tell socket subst open eof pwd glob list pid exec auto_load_index time 
unknown eval lassign lrange fblocked lsearch auto_import gets case lappend 
proc throw break variable llength auto_execok return linsert error catch 
clock info split array if fconfigure coroutine concat join lreplace source 
fcopy global switch auto_qualify update close cd for auto_load file append 
lreverse format lmap only_commands unload read package set namespace binary 
scan apply trace seek zlib while chan flush after vwait dict uplevel continue
 try foreach lset rename aaaaaaaaaa fileevent yieldto regexp lrepeat upvar
 tailcall encoding expr unset load regsub interp exit puts incr lindex lsort
 tclLog string yield
```

Why the **lreplace** seems not working?
Can someone explain me where is the problem?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far ?

Comment: this is an exercise, for now I didn't write anything

Comment: Even more so for an exercise. What have you tried, what do you think, etc? Exercises are supposed to test your comprehension of a subject, or nudge you to do some research by yourself.

Comment: Where did you find this exercise exactly?

Comment: You're missing `info procs`. See https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm

Comment: Can you find a command (perhaps a subcommand of `info`) that can distinguish if a *particular* command is a procedure?

Comment: I do all of this, removing from the list I get from [info commands] the elements of the list returned from [info proc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lreplace $rawList $pos $pos
```

From the [`lreplace` documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lreplace.htm) (Emphasis added):

> `lreplace` **returns a new list** formed by replacing ...

You're not doing anything with the new list it returns. Try changing that line to

```
set rawList [lreplace $rawList $pos $pos]
```